# How can I understand 'rather than' in this context?

Tags: grammar

> At the same time, operators of the first printing presses run by steam rather than by hand found it possible to produce a thousand pages in an hour **rather than** thirty.
>
> from TOFEL TPO 06

I have two explanations:

1. ...it possible to produce **a thousand pages rather than thirty pages** in an hour.
2. ...it possible to produce a thousand pages in **an hour rather than thirty hours**.

Google tells me the first explanation is right, but why?

How can I distinguish it in general context?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is what I first thought it meant. I think that's the natural interpretation for a native speaker.

When I read the sentence carefully I understood your question. In fact, either meaning is defensible. The sentence is ambiguous.

I can't cite a grammatical reason for preferring one to the other.

I don't think it's a fair TOEFL question.

By coincidence, both readings say about the same thing since 30 times 30 is close to 1000.

Comment: I agree with your answer. If meaning 2 were intended, though, I think it would more likely be said "a thousand pages in **one** hour rather than thirty.", to emphasize that it is hours being compared rather than pages.